# Understanding C++ code - "Get the number of digits in an int"

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am having trouble understanding how exactly this code works:

```
int length = 1;
int x = 234567545;
while (x /= 10)
   length++;
```

It is supposed to count the number of digits in the int variable. I don't get how the `while` loop is working. Does the loop just go to zero and stop by default? Also, why is the length starting at 1?

Comment: Zero means false. Think about that regarding how that loop ends. The final iteration (where `x < 10` is true), will break the loop, but not account for that final digit, thus the starting point of `1` requirement.

Comment: Step through your program with a debugger and *watch* the value of the `x` variable.  BTW, `/=` means `x = x / 10`.

Comment: As an aside: a simpler way to get the number of digits for a positive number is `ceil(log10(x))`.

Comment: [For other approaches, see this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601592/counting-digits-using-while-loop).

Comment: @duskwuff … and get a crash when x <= 0, and the wrong answer when x = 10, 100, 1000, etc.

Comment: If you still don't get it, it is the same as `x = x / 10; while ( x != 0 ) {
   length++; x = x / 10; }`

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree. The reason given is off-topic if anything. OP didn't ask for recommendations regarding books or tools etc.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because I don't think it should have been closed for being off-topic

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are three things that might be suspicious for you if you are a C++ beginner:

First thing might be operator `/=`, which combines an integral division (i.e. without remainder), with an assignment. So `x /= 10` actually is the same as `x = x / 10`.

Second, each expression in C++ has - after having been evaluated - a value. For an assignment like `(x = 0)`, the result is the value of `x` after the assignment, i.e. `0` in this case.

Third, a condition like `if (x) ...` with `x` being of integral type has in C++ the same meaning as `if(x != 0)`, i.e. it is `false` if `x` equals `0`, and it is `true` if `x` is anything else but `0`.

All together: `while ( x /= 10 )` means assign `x` the value of an integral division by `10` and then compare the value to `0`. If `0` is reached, the loop ends.

BTW: `length` starts with `1`, because any number, even `0`, comprises at least one digit.

Comment: I suspect the explanation of the third point rubbed some people the wrong way because it misrepresents the truth a little, but personally I think it's an acceptable abstraction for this level of difficulty.

Comment: In that case, just add "for x having type `int`".

Answer (score 27):

x /= 10 continuously divides x by 10, which will make it 0 eventually and cause the while loop to terminate due to 0 being interpreted as false (and any other value than 0 as true).

The reason it starts at length = 1 is because there is always at least 1 digit in the number: if x was from 0 to 9 inclusive, then x /= 10 would cause x to become 0 immediately, meaning nothing inside the loop would execute. Therefore, if length started at 0, it would never get to be incremented to 1 which would be wrong if x was a single digit large.

Manually calculating this example by hand:

1. 234567545 / 10 = 23456754, which is true, so the while loop continues and length becomes 2.
2. 23456754 / 10 = 2345675, true. length becomes 3.
3. 2345675 / 10 = 234567, true. length becomes 4.
4. 234567 / 10 = 23456, true. length becomes 5.
5. 23456 / 10 = 2345, true. length becomes 6.
6. 2345 / 10 = 234, true. length becomes 7.
7. 234 / 10 = 23, true. length becomes 8.
8. 23 / 10 = 2, true. length becomes 9.
9. 2 / 10 = 0, false. The while loop stops with length equal 9.

Answer (score 8):

The loop

```
while (x /= 10) {
  length++;
}
```

will go until the result of `x /= 10` evaluates to `false`, since `0` means `false` it will go until `x /= 10` is `0`. Integer division truncates, ensuring the condition will be reached. This can be illustrated by adding a simple debug statement, i.e.

```
while (x /= 10) {
  length++;
  std::cout << length << " " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Which outputs

```
2 23456754
3 2345675
4 234567
5 23456
6 2345
7 234
8 23
9 2
```

Answer (score 6):

Integer division will truncate the remainder, so continually dividing a number with integer division will inevitably result in zero.

Dividing a number `n` by 10 while incrementing a counter `i` once for each time the resulting quotient (stored back into `n`) is not zero will result in the `i` containing the number of digits for the base-10 representation of `n`.

Answer (score 5):

It helps to understand two parts:

- what is "/="
- when does the loop terminate

## Explain "/="

This:

```
x /= 10
```

is the same as:

```
x = x / 10
```

## Explain when the loop terminates

The `while` loop terminates, when the condition is false. And 0 is equivalent to false.

```
while (condition) {
    length++;
}
```

So x is, with every pass through the loop, divided by 10, until is is 0. That terminates the loop.

So, the condition is two things at the same time:

- it is a value, that is compared to 0. The loop continues until this
  evaluates to 0.
- it is an assignment: x gets a new value with every evaluation. It's divided by 10, so it converges to 0.

Answer (score -11):

This is a bit of stupidity you'll often see in C/C++, taking advantage of the fact that TRUE is implemented as non-zero, and FALSE as zero*. So x is repeatedly divided by 10, and the expression eventually becomes zero, so the loop stops.

Though confusing, this works - until the day someone in a hurry changes x from an int to a double :-)  Much clearer and less failure-prone to write "while (x /= 10 >= 1)", or even to put the math inside the loop body rather than in the condition.

*IMHO one of the few shortcomings of C is that it didn't have an explicit logical type, as FORTRAN did.

Comment: It would be best if you keep the rants about what you don't like in C++ out of your answer...

Comment: 1) Rather too opinionated. 2) Absolutely not limited to C/C++, but rather common to a lot of programming languages. 3) To catch things like "someone changing a type in a hurry" (and you should never change working code "in a hurry"), we're writing and executing tests. 4) Contracting logic into a condition like that is not at all confusing to anyone but a beginner at programming. (Next thing you argue about zero-based indexing...) 5) Question is C++, not C, and C++ *does* have an explicit logical type (as does C since C99).

Comment: 6) Your "fix" doesn't work with negative numbers. 7) Code counts number of digits in an int, which is undefined for a double anyway.

Comment: Your change does not work, because `>=` has higher precedence ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `/=`. So, `10 >= 1` is evaluated to `1`, and `x /= 1` leaves the value of `x` unchanged, leading to an infinite loop.